# MKAnnotationView Click delegate not calling after first time

Tags: mapkit, mkannotationview

I Have added default MKAnnotationView with only an image . The Annotations are plotting correctly. 
Now comes an issue . Every time  i click on an annotation view it works the first time , then again i click on it the delegate not getting called, but if i click on any other annotation view delegate is getting called.

I have seen comments regarding setting `canShowCallout = false`  and set it as false.

i Have done following things till Now

1 . set `canShowCallout = false`

2 . Add setting `Title`  value for annotation

it will be great if somebody can share a solution for this  ?

Comment: Can you show delegate (mapView:didSelect) code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have also faced a similar bug in my project. In my case the issue was with the CalloutView . Even if you set `canShowCallOut == false` or not at all setting `canShowCallOut` value, when you click on the annotation view the callout view is getting presented somehow in a hidden state. So the user doesn’t recognize this. So when you click for the second time on the annotation view, as the callout is still present it will not trigger the delegate method.

I solved my issue by calling mapview’s  `deselectAnnotation(_:animated:)` method after all the processing is completed in 
`mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` method. So the invisible callout view will get dismissed and the annotation will be clickable  again .

Hope this will help

Comment: Great !!!!!. This is the same issue i had. Now on deselecting annotation view it works as expected !!!!!